# Convert list to a string with double quotes

Tags: python, python-2.x

For an external application I need to send a command as a string, like this:

`["START", "1", "2", "3", "4", "STOP"]`

Note the double quotes!

I create this command with the following function:

```
def create_command(amount):
    command = ["START"]
    list = create_list(amount)
    command += list
    command += ["STOP"]
    command = str(command ) 
    command = command.replace("\'", "\"")
    return command
```

And I create a list from a given number with the following function:

```
def create_list(data):
    list = []
    data = str(data)
    for letter in data:
        list.append(letter)
    return list
```

Is the a way to make both functions more pythonic and not so straightforward?  I don't really like them now, they look a bit clumpsy and I think there must be a better way do the thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`create_list` is building a list of all the items in the `str`ing form of `data`. And so you can change it to:

```
def create_list(data):
    return list(str(data))
```

I find it easier to read `create_command` if you merge some of the lines together:

```
def create_command(amount):
    command = ["START"] + create_list(amount) + ["STOP"]
    return str(command).replace("\'", "\"")
```

And so you can merge the above two changes together:

```
def create_command(amount):
    command = ["START"] + list(str(amount)) + ["STOP"]
    return str(command).replace("\'", "\"")
```

---

Expanding further, rather than using `str.replace` you can use `json.dumps` to format the list. This has the benefit that it will escape `'` and `"` characters for you, which your code doesn't correctly handle. (Thanks [Mathias](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/84718/mathias-ettinger))

```
import json


def create_command(amount):
    command = ["START"] + list(str(amount)) + ["STOP"]
    return json.dumps(command)
```

Comment: You could also make composing the list a bit neater using iterable unpacking: `["START", *str(amount), "STOP"]`  (available since Python 3.5).

Comment: Why on Earth is `json` buried at the bottom of your answer?

Comment: @jpmc26 because my primary purpose is to review the code, and so I work my way up to the best code. It wouldn't make sense to go the other way.

Comment: It makes sense for the best code to be the first thing a reader sees so that they don't get confused about where you're headed. It also makes it harder to miss the best code when doing an initial skim.

Comment: @jpmc26 what you're suggesting sounds like you want me to promote people to just steal my code and not learn anything. I want people to learn something, and so won't make you suggested changes.

Comment: If you don't want people to "steal your code," then you shouldn't post it on a public forum that licenses all content under Creative Commons. It's not about not learning. It's about making it easier to learn. Having incremental, working code in the middle that 1. can be taken and used just as easily as the final code, and 2. still contains a lot of poor code from the OP's original, just makes it even harder to learn, since it's harder to parse out what's good and what's bad.

Comment: @jpmc26 I find it easier to learn by example, and so write my answers in that form. Also, as I said before, I have a problem with just stealing and not learning.

Answer (score 10):

Don't overshadow built in functions

`list` is already a built in. When you would try to use `list()` later on you'd get an Error.

## Alternative

You need to send a string. Instead of creating a list and then converting to a string you can build the string from the start.

```
def create_list(data):
    return ', '.join(['"{}"'.format(c) for c in str(data)])

def create_cmd(data):
    return '["START", {}, "STOP"]'.format(create_list(data))
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I don't actually use ``list`` as a name, I just changed the variable names for the question and absolutely forgot that there is a function with this name.

Comment: Eh. `list` is an obvious name, and shadowing names in a small scope isn’t at all problematic. I agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sure in this small scope it doesn't really matter, but it is not a good habit to get into. And is worth mentioning at a code review

Answer (score 9):

The python `json.dumps` function from stdlib can do this for you.

```
from json import dumps
result = build_your_list()  # ['a', 'b']
dumps(result)  # '["a", "b"]'
```

EDIT: I only just noticed that using this was recommended at the bottom of an already existing answer - but I think this deserves a full answer. I consider it much cleaner than the potentially inaccurate string manipulation answers.